# Why edit menu not visible when current view use grouping?

Tags: library, grouping, view

i have a document library with a customized grouping. In the view setting i enabled the column "Name (linked to document with edit menu) )". Problem is that the edit menu didn't show up.
For testing purpose i made a secound view as a normal table view without any grouping and enabled the same columns. In this view the edit menu is visible and all works as expected.
I tested this with an admin account so i don't think it's a security issue.

Some ideas would be great!

Thanks, John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an old browser version. I installed IE 9 and it worked as excpected. Checking browser version is allways a good idea to start troubleshooting with such issues :)